# Express.js Routes Response Synchronously

Tags: rest, express, asynchronous, async-await

**Problem**

After 3 months of coding with Node.js Express.js, MongoDB and MSSQL i realized when a user run a complex query (it takes 15 seconds) other users is not getting any response until end of large query response.

**Test Code**

So i decided to create a simple app and test it.

```
const config = {
    port : 8080
};
const express = require('express');

/** RUN */
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);

/**
 * ROUTES
 */

app.get("/abc", function (req, res,next) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
    //next();
});

app.get("/", function (req, res,next) {
    var seconds = 10;
    var newDate = new Date().getTime() + seconds * 1000;
    var waitTill = new Date(newDate);
    while(waitTill > new Date()){
        console.log("waiting  : " + (newDate - new Date().getTime()));
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
    //next();
});

/**
 * START
 */

http.listen(config.port,function (error) {
    if(error) logger.error(error);
    console.info("Server running on http://localhost:" + config.port);
});
```

**Result**

I made a request to localhost:8080/ and localhost:8080/abc with given order.

http://localhost:8080/ (10.02 s)
[image]

http://localhost:8080/abc (10.02 s)
[image]

**Conclusion**

1. Express.js route requests are async.
2. Express.js route responses are sync.

**Question**

How can i create async responses with express.js route?

Comment: You're blocking the event loop using `while (waitTill > new Date())`, which isn't a good method to mimic "a complex query". I assume that it takes the database server 15 seconds before sending back the query results? If so, then Node.js will just be waiting patiently, and it won't block the event loop (in other words: there's probably _another_ problem in your code that is causing the stalls).

Comment: @robertklep I don't understand. These two routes are seperate. Why is this happening? I thought when i call different urls it works like seperate threads.

Comment: All JS code in Node.js runs in the same thread, so when one request blocks the event loop, no other requests can be serviced in the mean time.

Comment: @robertklep Ok. So how can i avoid to wait other users? Some queries are taking too long.

Comment: Typically, when a database query takes a lot of time, it's not an issue because that time is spent on the database server, not on the Node.js server. The latter is just waiting for the database results to be sent back, and (I/O) waiting doesn't block the event loop. That's why I think there might be another issue that's causing your problems, but we first have to establish if it's the query (and no pre-/postprocessing of the results on Node.js) that's taking 15 seconds.

Comment: @robertklep I got it thank you so much.